# What happens when List<Integer> A = List<Integer> B?

Tags: java, arraylist

What happens when I do this:

```
List<Integer> listA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> ListB = new ArrayList<Integer>();

listA = ...filled with some data...
listB = ...filled with some other data...

listA.clear();
listA = listB;
```

Does values copies or just re-reference? If I now (after this code) call `listA.clear()` **again**, will `listB` clear as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, after `listA = listB` the variable `listA` references the same list as `listB`. There is no copy-constructor in Java like you have it in C++ etc.

Answer (score 2):

just the value of reference will get copied, and so both of them would be referring to same Object

Answer (score 1):

Only primitive types are copied by value, if you do the above you'll have listA and listB referencing the same list, so whatever you do with listA will have the same effect on listB and vice-verse.
and if you want to lose the reference just set one of the variables to null.

Answer (score 0):

No, `listA` and `listB` are two different list of integers, They are not related to each other. If you do a `clear()` on the `ListA`, `ListB` will not be affected at all. In your case  at the end `ListA` reference is changed and the variable is now pointed to `ListB`. So, Both of these variables point to one List that is `ListB`. So, any action on any of these references will have the same effects. `ListA` object is already empty, it contains nothing. and there is not any way to refer that object.

Comment: @sandalone Yes, That is right. In that case you will have both the list object empty.

Comment: this listA = listB; will copy the reference of listB to listA, so even if at the beginning they were unrelated, at that moment they start to have the same reference, it doesn't matter whether listA was or not empty.